# Virtualizing star schema

Tags: virtualization, etl, data-warehouse, star-schema

Does anyone have experinces about virtualizing star schema model?
i.e. making database views which contain the data for facts and dimensions, instead of having them in physical tables.

Comment: Not directly. I have a staging DB which refers to source systems. Data to dimensions and facts are loaded from this staging area (ETL). These fact and dimension tables are now in their own separate DW database. I was now thinking about putting them into views, instead of those physical tables.

Comment: Your star schema should be physical tables.  The reason you put data in a data warehouse is to gain select performance.  Views hinder performance.

Comment: Are you applying any transformation when moving data from stage to DW? Aren't you afraid that these transformations will make the views complex and therefore slow?